# How to receive and handle multiple TCP stream sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, pickle

I would like to send the location of a moving point to a server via TCP with the socket module. That point location is updated at each iteration of a `for` loop and is sent in the form of a tuple `(x, y)` that has been serialized with pickle `dumps` methods.

**Problem:**

On the server side, it seems that I only get to receive the location from the first iteration of that loop. As if all the following updated positions had been skipped or lost in the process.

I can’t say for sure what is the reason behind this behavior but my bet is that I am not correctly setting things on the server side. I suspect the data to be sent entirely but not processed adequately on reception due to some mistakes that I am probably doing with the socket module (I am completely new to the world of network interfaces).

**Code:**

*--client side--*

```
#Python3.7
import socket
import pickle
import math

HOST = "127.0.0.1" 
PORT = 12000

den = 20
rad = 100
theta = math.tau / den

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT)) #connect to server

    for step in range(1000):
        i = step%den
        x = math.cos(i*theta) * rad
        y = math.sin(i*theta) * rad
        data = pickle.dumps((x, y), protocol=0) 
        sock.sendall(data)
```

*--server side--*

```
#Jython2.7
import pickle
import socket

HOST = "127.0.0.1"   
PORT = 12000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)

while True:
    connection, address = s.accept()

    if connection:
        data = connection.recv(4096)
        print(pickle.loads(data)) # <-- only print once (first location)
```

Comment: You need to put `connection, address = s.accept()` outside the while loop otherwise your server will wait for a new connection everytime

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion but this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, after a deeper look you also have an issue with the way your are receiving data.
`connection.recv(4096)` will return any amount of bytes between 0 and 4096 not every time a complete "data" message is received. To handle this you could send a header before sending you json indicating how much data should be received

Comment: Interesting, would you mind to provide an example ?

Comment: See the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put connection, address = s.accept() outside the while loop otherwise your server will wait for a new connection every time.

You also have an issue with the way your are receiving data. `connection.recv(4096)` will return any amount of bytes between 0 and 4096 not every time a complete "data" message is received. To handle this you could send a header before sending you json indicating how much data should be received
By adding a header, you will make sure the data messages you are sending will be received properly.

The header in this example is a four bytes int indicating the size of data.
Server

```py
import pickle
import socket
import struct

HEADER_SIZE = 4
HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 12000


def receive(nb_bytes, conn):
    # Ensure that exactly the desired amount of bytes is received
    received = bytearray()
    while len(received) < nb_bytes:
        received += conn.recv(nb_bytes - len(received))

    return received

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
connection, address = s.accept()

while True:
    # receive header
    header = receive(HEADER_SIZE, connection)
    data_size = struct.unpack(">i", header)[0]
    # receive data
    data = receive(data_size, connection)
    print(pickle.loads(data))
```

Client

```py
import socket
import pickle
import math

HEADER_SIZE = 4
HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 12000

den = 20
rad = 100
theta = math.tau / den

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT)) #connect to server

    for step in range(1000):
        i = step%den
        x = math.cos(i*theta) * rad
        y = math.sin(i*theta) * rad
        data = pickle.dumps((x, y), protocol=0)
        # compute header by taking the byte representation of the int
        header = len(data).to_bytes(HEADER_SIZE, byteorder ='big')
        sock.sendall(header + data)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Apologies for the reply, I have difficulties to port your "Server" script to Python 2.7 (actually Jython 2.7 as stated in my original script). `int.from_bytes(header, byteorder ='big')` returns an error and I don't know what could be the equivalent in Python 2. Neither `int(str(header), 16)` or `int(str(header).encode('hex'), 16)` seems to work on my machine.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code with `data_size = struct.unpack(">i", header)[0]` to ensure cross compatibility

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your answer. I learned a lot from it. Unfortunately I can't run it in Jython 2.7 but it seems to work fine with Python 2.7 . +1

Comment: You're welcome. What error do you get on Jyhton 2.7 ?

Comment: `TypeError: StringIO(): 1st arg can’t be coerced to org.python.core.PyArray`